# How to check that the Braid group has the known presentation?

Tags: group-theory, isometry, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, braid-groups

Why we are sure that the presentation for the braid group is

$$
\mathcal{B}_n= \left\langle \sigma_1 , \dots, \sigma_{n-1} \vert
\mathcal{R}_n
\right\rangle,
$$

where $$\mathcal{R}_n=\left\{
\begin{smallmatrix}
\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i=\sigma_{i+1}\sigma_i\sigma_{i+1} \ \forall \ 1\leq i\leq n-2, \\ \sigma_i\sigma_j = \sigma_j\sigma_i \ \mbox{if } \vert i-j\vert \ge 2 
\end{smallmatrix}
\right\}$$

How can we prove it? It's obvious that those relations are true in the Braid Group, but how we know that those are the unique relations needed?

The definition I'm basing is the group of isotopy classes of braids of $n$ strands.

Comment: What is your definition of the braid group?

Comment: I understand it as the group of isotopy classes of $n$ paths that start and end in the same set of points.

Comment: This is a theorem of Artin: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969218?origin=crossref.

Comment: A proof should be also in Joan Birman's book on the braid group.